# Dollar value of coins and calculating interest compounded annually

Tags: java, beginner, homework, finance

I've made this program to do a few integer calculations.  Do the methods for converting the numbers look good?  Do you have any other basic tips?

```
/* Dollar Value of Coins, Investment Compounded Annually
 * B, Morris
 */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;
public class HW3_DollarValuOfCoinsInvestmentCompoundedAnnually {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
NumberFormat priceFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

//Dollar value of coins

System.out.println("How many quarters do you have?");
double quarters = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.println("How many dimes do you have?");
double dimes = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.println("How many nickles do you have?");
double nickles = keyboard.nextDouble();

quarters = quarters * (0.25);
dimes = dimes * (0.10);
nickles = nickles * (0.05);
double total =(quarters + dimes + nickles);
System.out.println("You have: " + priceFormat.format(total));


//Investment Compounded Annually

System.out.println("What is the initial investment?");
double investment = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.println("At what intrest rate is the intrest compounded annually?");
double intrestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

double futureValueFive = investment * (Math.pow((1 + intrestRate), (double) 5));
System.out.println("In five years the investment will be worth : " + priceFormat.format(futureValueFive));

double futureValueTen = investment * (Math.pow((1 + intrestRate), (double) 10));
System.out.println("In ten years the investment will be worth : " + priceFormat.format(futureValueTen));

double futureValueTwenty = investment * (Math.pow((1 + intrestRate), (double) 20));
System.out.println("In twenty years the investment will be worth : " + priceFormat.format(futureValueTwenty));


}
}
```

Comment: In general, it is better to store financial values in [decimal]( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx). In this case it does not really matter because you're doing other floating point operations, but it is worth keeping it in mind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Choose the right types

You used `double` for the coin types, for example:

> ```
> System.out.println("How many quarters do you have?");
> double quarters = keyboard.nextDouble();
> quarters = quarters * (0.25);
> ```

To the question "how many quarters ...",
it's logical to get an integer (whole number) as the answer, not a `double`.

I can guess that you choose the `double` type because you want to use the `quarters` variable for two different purposes:

- Count the quarters
- Count the dollar value of the quarters

These are conflicting meanings, and the right thing to do is to not mix them,
for example:

```
int quarters = keyboard.nextInt();
double dollarValueOfQuarters = quarters * .25;
```

#### The Single Responsibility Principle

The `main` is doing too much: it has too many responsibilities:

1. Calculate the dollar value of coins
2. Calculate the compound interest

It would be better to split the method into, and give them a name according to their main responsibility, for example:

```
private static void calculateDollarValueOfCoins(Scanner scanner, NumberFormat moneyFormat) { ... }

private static void calculateCompoundInterest(Scanner scanner, NumberFormat moneyFormat) { ... }

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    NumberFormat moneyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    calculateDollarValueOfCoins(scanner, moneyFormat);
    calculateCompoundInterest(scanner, moneyFormat);
}
```

Now the responsibilities are clearly separated.
I also renamed some variables to better match their purposes:

- `scanner` instead of `keyboard`, because you don't really "scan" things from a keyboard. A scanner is a more abstract concept than a keyboard: for all you care, the input values could come as radio signals from the moon, as long as it implements the Scanner's API, your method can work.
- `moneyFormat` instead of `priceFormat`, which works for both responsibilities nicely: the dollar value of your coins is certainly not a "price", and the worth of your investment is not *exactly* a "price". They are both about money, and formatting money, so this more general name seems appropriate.

#### Modeling coins

It might be a good idea to model coins using an enum:

```
enum Coin {
    NICKLE(.05),
    DIME(.1),
    QUARTER(.25);

    private final double value;

    Coin(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And to add a helper class for adding coins:

```
private static class CoinAdder {
    private double value = 0;

    CoinAdder addCoins(Coin coin, int number) {
        value += coin.value * number;
        return this;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This way, the `calculateDollarValueOfCoins` method I suggested above can be implemented in a somewhat more natural way,
and without embedding the dollar value of coins in it:

```
private static void calculateDollarValueOfCoins(Scanner scanner, NumberFormat moneyFormat) {
    System.out.println("How many quarters do you have?");
    int quarters = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many dimes do you have?");
    int dimes = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many nickles do you have?");
    int nickles = scanner.nextInt();

    double total = new CoinAdder()
            .addCoins(Coin.QUARTER, quarters)
            .addCoins(Coin.DIME, dimes)
            .addCoins(Coin.NICKLE, nickles)
            .getValue();
    System.out.println("You have: " + moneyFormat.format(total));
}
```

Now we have separated the responsibilities even further:
`calculateDollarValueOfCoins` doesn't know anymore the value of the different types of coins, and it doesn't know how to add them.
Those responsibilities are delegated to the `Coin` enum and the `CoinAdder` class,
which is a good thing.

#### Quick tips

Instead of this:

> ```
> quarters = quarters * (0.25);
> ```

Better:

```
quarters *= 0.25;
```

You can write `0.25` as `.25`.

You can write `5.` instead of `(double) 5`.

#### Suggested implementation

Putting the above suggestions together, something like this would be better:

```
class InterestCalculator {

    enum Coin {
        NICKLE(.05),
        DIME(.1),
        QUARTER(.25);

        private final double value;

        Coin(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private static class CoinAdder {
        private double value = 0;

        CoinAdder addCoins(Coin coin, int number) {
            value += coin.value * number;
            return this;
        }

        public double getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private static void calculateDollarValueOfCoins(Scanner scanner, NumberFormat moneyFormat) {
        System.out.println("How many quarters do you have?");
        int quarters = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many dimes do you have?");
        int dimes = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many nickles do you have?");
        int nickles = scanner.nextInt();

        double total = new CoinAdder()
                .addCoins(Coin.QUARTER, quarters)
                .addCoins(Coin.DIME, dimes)
                .addCoins(Coin.NICKLE, nickles)
                .getValue();
        System.out.println("You have: " + moneyFormat.format(total));
    }

    private static void calculateCompoundInterest(Scanner scanner, NumberFormat moneyFormat) {
        System.out.println("What is the initial investment?");
        double investment = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("At what intrest rate is the intrest compounded annually?");
        double intrestRate = scanner.nextDouble();

        double futureValueFive = investment * Math.pow(1 + intrestRate, 5.);
        System.out.println("In five years the investment will be worth : " + moneyFormat.format(futureValueFive));

        double futureValueTen = investment * Math.pow(1 + intrestRate, 10.);
        System.out.println("In ten years the investment will be worth : " + moneyFormat.format(futureValueTen));

        double futureValueTwenty = investment * Math.pow(1 + intrestRate, 20.);
        System.out.println("In twenty years the investment will be worth : " + moneyFormat.format(futureValueTwenty));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat moneyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        calculateDollarValueOfCoins(scanner, moneyFormat);
        calculateCompoundInterest(scanner, moneyFormat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi why dint you use an interface? Any reasons particularly? Why are you declaring value both in Enum and coinaddr

Comment: It's simple, I guess. I don't claim it's perfect. Also keep in mind that it's a beginner question, I did't want to overengineer it too much. As per `CoinAdder.value`, notice that it means something completely different from `Coin.value`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of calculating the total value of the coins in `main()`:

> ```
> quarters = quarters * (0.25);
> dimes = dimes * (0.10);
> nickles = nickles * (0.05);
> ```

consider using separate methods for each type of coin:

```
public static double getQuarters(int quarters) {
    return quarters * 0.25;
}
```

```
public static double getDimes(int dimes) {
    return dimes * 0.10;
}
```

```
public static double getNickles(int nickles) {
    return nickles * 0.05;
}
```

Try not to keep everything in `main()`, especially if your program starts to get larger.  Try to decompose to multiple smaller methods that each have a single responsibility.

Comment: I would rephrase that: *you should avoid putting everything in `main()`*. Or even add: *try to decompose to multiple smaller methods that each have a single responsibility* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would also make an `interface` of these methods:

```
interface investmentCompound
{
    double getQuarters(double numOfQuarters);   
    double getDimes(double numOfDimes);
    double getNickles(double numOfNickles);
    double performCalculations();
    double formatPrice(double priceToFormat);
    ...

}
```

- The above will give your class a much better design and help you better code as well. Always program in such a way that when anyone reads your code, the method and variable names are self-explanatory on what your class is doing.
- Give your `main()` function the minimal capability to just call methods and variables instead of declaring everything there.
- In the real world, you will always have an API i.e. getters and setters and methods like how I mentioned in the interface above.  This is better practice, so when someone wants to call your code, they should be able to use the methods.
- Since you are going to use `numOfNickles`, `numOfQuarters`, `numOfDimes` variable names several times, it's best to declare that at class level, so declare them as class variables instead of in `main()`.

Comment: The arguments for the getters should be an integer type.

Comment: In what way does that particular collection of methods constitute a coherent interface? Would you ever have more than one implementation of such an interface? If not, why bother declaring it as an interface?